# create repository with VS Code not working

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I downloaded vs code and tried to get it to make a new repository for my project and sync the to. I have never worked with GitHub or VS Code before so I have no idea what I am doing.

Under source control it first showed me that there were 10k changes on whatever (no idea). I than made a new folder put all the files there and tried again. it didn't show the 10k changes but when I pressed publish to GitHub it said repository not found (which repository does it refer to? I have not included anything). I asked chatgpt but it couldn't help: there is no .git file, the command Git: Initialize Repository is not found and the git extension is installed.

Edit: after some time it now again shows the 10k changes and under source control repositories it says  (my name) Git main  but none of the GitHub repositories I created for testing

all help is welcome. I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: you are not the first with the 10k+ option, do a SO search

Comment: Version control is complicated. I would suggest [reading the documentation and tutorials](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol). If after that you are still having problems, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no .git file

Be aware, the `.git` folder created by Git is generally a hidden one.

And if you see many changes on your first commit, chances are you have initialized your repository *directly* under `$HOME` or under `%USERPROFILE%`

Delete that hidden `.git`, then retry from command-line (before switching back to VSCode), with a `git init .` done from within your project root folder.
As well as a `git remote add origin https://github.com/me/myRemoteRepo`

Comment: Yeah Thanks a lot! I found a .git file in my users folder. now everything works. Is there a chance that that file is important for anything, like an external program or the os (I personally dont need the backups)? for now I didnt delet the .git file completely

Comment: @Lordcode No, you can delete that folder `.git`. And do a `git init .` (The dot is important) inside the root folder of your project.